# Есть ли редактор под написание драйвера?

Tags: c++, c, драйвер

Есть ли такой редактор для написания драйвера под Windows, который будет подсказывать функции WDK, по возможности чтобы в нем можно было бы драйвер скомпилировать и запустить нажав там на кнопку?

Comment: Какую ручку использовать для написания романа? Шариковую или чернильную? Или гелевую? И можно ли использовать клавиатуру? Вроде бы все великие романы XIX века написаны от руки, без компьютеров? Я пробовал писать шариковой ручкой зеленого цвета, но не нашел вдохновения - оно, наверное, поставляется только с другим цветом?...

Comment: Любой используйте какой нравится....

Comment: Не ну мне ж надо чтобы подсказывал, тут вдохновение не причем

Comment: А чем вам Visual Studio не угодила?

Comment: Так вот счас в ней и разбираюсь, может и оно хз

Answer (score 5):

notepad.exe - отличный редактор, в том числе отлично подходит для написания драйверов под вашу платформу, есть уже в составе операционной системы, под которую вы хотите писать драйвер.

В качестве альтернативы, если вы *не такой как все*, можно попробовать редактор Sublime, на удивление удобный редактор для небольших файлов со вкладками, быстрый, умеет мгновернно закрываться. Вот только без плагинов он почти не отличается от notepad.exe и его брата notepad++, а в качестве репозитория плагинов огромная помойка, где с одной стороны, есть почти все на свете, а с другой - это всё очень низкого качества. Еще вариант, попробовать старый добрый Eclipse, но это уже достаточно тяжелое приложение.

В общем, писать драйвер можно в чем угодно. Да и на чем угодно тоже: https://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=47141

> Добавлен API WebUSB, позволяющий напрямую взаимодействовать со
>   специализированными периферийными устройствами, подключаемыми через
>   порт USB, для которых отсутствует штатная системная поддержка. WebUSB
>   позволяет организовать работу с такими устройствами без установки в
>   систему специализированных драйверов, благодаря предоставлению
>   возможности прямого обращения к устройству из web-приложения (логика
>   низкоуровневого взаимодействия задаётся в web-приложении, т.е. драйвер
>   реализуется на JavaScript);

В общем, не в редакторе дело